# Adding g+1 button in Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, google-plus, google-play-services, google-plus-one

I wish to add g+1 in my LibGdx based android gaming app. I am following this link to understand the g+1 related coding.
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend?hl=en

In Libgdx, we do not have a relative layout to have the button "com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton". Hence I plan to draw a g+1 button.  But I wonder how to get the annotation bubble. getAnnotation() method is protected.

Please advice.